# Navegación entre componentes de Angular2

Tags: angularjs-2.0

Como se podria hacer para navegar entre componentes, sin utilizar router-outlet, lo que quiero es al hacer click en un boton de un componente me lleve completamente hacia el otro componente, no solo me cambie la seccion del router-outlet.

Me explico un poco mejor. Tengo este codigo, cada uno de los enlaces router-link me carga el contenido en la etiqueta router-outlet.

```
<a md-raised-button routerLink="/principal" routerLinkActive="active">Principal</a>
<a md-raised-button routerLink="/login" routerLinkActive="active">Login</a>
<a md-raised-button routerLink="/acerca" fragment="shield">A cerca de</a>

<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

Lo que se desea hacer es una navegación entre componentes, si hago click en el enlace login, me dirijo completamente hacia el componente de la ruta /login, no cambio el  componente en el router-outlet.

Comment: ¡Bienvenido a SOes! favor de revisar [¿Qué tipo de preguntas debo evitar preguntar?](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask), asimismo, tienes la opción de [editar tu pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/52819/edit). Si tuvieras alguna duda adicional podrías visitar el [Centro de Ayuda](http://es.stackoverflow.com/help)

Comment: @KarlosCode , si estas viendo esto, deberias venir al [chat general](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/30872/stack-overflow-en-espanol)  para discutir esto, no en una [edicion de la pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/32028) . O tambien puedes hacer una pregunta en [Meta](http://meta.es.stackoverflow.com/)

Comment: ¿Ya solucionaste el problema?

Answer (score 2):

app.component.ts:

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

    constructor( private router: Router ) {}
```

--- En el metodo asociado al (click) del boton:

```
miMetodo(){
    this.router.navigate(['/MiComponente']);
}
```

Y lógicamente la ruta tiene que estar asociada a un componente en el app.routing.ts:

```
import { MiComponente } from './mi.componente';

const appRoutes: Routes = [
  { path: 'MiComponente', component: MiComponente }
];

export const AppRouting: ModuleWithProviders = RouterModule.forRoot(appRoutes);
```

Comment: La respuesta contestaba la pregunta antes de la edición , ahora ha perdido el sentido. ¿Has probado a meter el router-outlet en un div y controlar la visivlidad con un Hidden?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta y tienes toda la razón, ahora ya no aplicaría para la pregunta. Y por lo que ahora comentas no seria muy optimo cargar componentes que no se van a ver, quisiera cambiar totalmente el componente o en su defecto, navegar entre paginas con  componentes específicos.

Answer (score 0):

Para lo que comentas en tu pregunta, deberías tener un router-outlet por encima de ese código, y que dependiendo de la ruta enseñe o esos componentes, u otra página totalmente distinta, pero el router router-outlet tal y como lo tienes, todas las redirecciones de componentes serán cargadas ahí.

Comment: Tienes algún ejemplo de muestra en el que me pueda guiar. Lo que comentas ya lo habia intentado pero me da la misma funcionalidad.

Comment: No tengo nada preparado, pero si puedes subir tu ejemplo a un plunk o algun sitio similar, te lo modifico y te lo resubo ;)